# Semantical error when using QueryBuilder with an expression

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with getting data from the database using the `expr()` method function. I would like to get data where `isPublic = true` and `objectType = $objectType` OR `user = $user` and `objectType = $objectType`, **no matter what the value of `isPublic` is**.

I'm getting this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'user-avatar)': Error: 'user' is not defined.
```

My code in repository:

```
    public function findByObjectType($objectType, $user)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

        return $qb->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('s.isPublic', true),
                $qb->expr()->eq('s.objectType', $objectType)
            ))
            ->orWhere($qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('s.user', $user->getId()),
                $qb->expr()->eq('s.objectType', $objectType)
            ))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

where: `$objectType = 'user-avatar'; $user = UserInterface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expr()->eq()` will treat the expression as literals, trying to use them literally as they appear on method call.

As [mentioned](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4603#issuecomment-162368630) by the library author:

> You are not using parameter binding. Expressions use string concatenation internally, so this outcome is actually expected.

In your case, you should be doing something like::

```php
 return $qb->where($qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('s.isPublic', ':true'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('s.objectType', ':objectType')
    ))
    ->orWhere($qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('s.user', ':userId'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('s.objectType', ':objectType')
    ))

    ->setParameter('true', true)
    ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
    ->setParameter('objectType', $objectType)

    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This way your code is easier to read, safer and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$qb->expr()->eq()` you will need supply the exact value for the query. In this case you need to change your query to something like this:

```
$qb->expr()->eq('s.objectType', '"' . $objectType .'"')
```

This way to string will be correctly quoted in the db query. The same goes for booleans by the way. Casting `true` to a string will result in `1`. That's why you didn't encounter an error in this case. `false` however gets cast to an empty string, which would result in an error.

To better understand what's going on, here is the part of code that converts the `eq()` expression to the query:

```
 /**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->leftExpr . ' ' . $this->operator . ' ' . $this->rightExpr;
}
```

Comment: Instead of '"' I did "'" and it helped, but @yivi solution is clearer :) Thanks for your reply!